# Python - Calling a variable exists in 3 classes

Tags: python, class, pyqt

I have a project with 3 classes, I will represent them as in the code below, in the first it will run class 1, and it must change the value of class 2, and when calling the variable in class 3 you should read the value we put in class 1...

but the code I made did not change  That value

```
class class1(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.models = class2()
        self.models.variable = 200



class class2(QWidget):
    variable = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()



class class3:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.models = class2()
        print(self.models.variable) # Here I want to show 200 but the value that appears is 0
```

There must be 3 classes as in the order, also class 1 must not be called in class 3

Comment: Why did you expect that?  You haven't involved `class1` at all.  Did you intend to create a `class`, and then refer to `obj.models`?

Comment: Because at first it works Class 2, then Class 1, and finally Class 3

Comment: No.  Nothing in that code ever creates a `class1`, so `class1.__init__` will never run.

Comment: Do you want each creation of a `class1` object to overwrite `class2.variable` so that every instance of class2 sees that new value? That seems like an odd thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make `class2` as a namespace to hold `variable`. So just do that:

```py
class class1(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.models = class2()
        class2.variable = 200



class class2(QWidget):
    variable = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()



class class3:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.models = class2()
        print(class2.variable)
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.  `class2.variable` will still print 0.

Comment: So why is that?

Comment: Because nothing here ever causes `class1.__init__` to be run.

Comment: Yes, it has given good results

Comment: @TimRoberts: Yes, I quite agree with your thinking, except I had the intuition that the OP meant that these were three different classes in three different modules and `class1` (being derived from `QMainWindow`) is created first, but imports `class2` which creates `variable = 0`. Finally instances of `class3` are created which read `class2.variable`.